# Safari Services crash [SFAuthenticationViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]

Tags: ios, crash, ios11

I'm having a crash very often in my app. It seems a crash from iOS system only happening in the latest iOS 11.

This is the crash

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18439d7ec objc_object::release() + 8
1  SafariServices                 0x1995d471c __75-[SFAuthenticationViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
2  UIKit                          0x18e5bf030 -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 1320
3  UIKit                          0x18e79e760 -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 44
4  UIKit                          0x18e5c2a20 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 188
5  UIKit                          0x18e38e9d8 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 116
6  UIKit                          0x18e38e7c8 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 252
7  UIKit                          0x18e38e260 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1128
8  UIKit                          0x18e38dde4 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 120
9  UIKit                          0x18e2b370c -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312
10 UIKit                          0x18e2b3418 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 296
11 UIKit                          0x18e2b34b8 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 456
12 QuartzCore                     0x188e57d6c CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 284
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1847f1048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1847fdb74 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016
15 CoreFoundation                 0x184e13f20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
16 CoreFoundation                 0x184e11afc __CFRunLoopRun + 2012
17 CoreFoundation                 0x184d322d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
18 GraphicsServices               0x186bc3f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
19 UIKit                          0x18e2df880 UIApplicationMain + 208
20 Jaumo                          0x1005674b4 main (main.m:20)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x18485656c start + 4
```

Not sure what is this crash. anyone can help with this issue?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jelly no yet, I’m still waiting for some help

Comment: Ok, I found it on my side. Maybe it will help you. Long story short, the login was called twice and that caused the crash.

Comment: @Jelly oh really?? You mean Facebook login right?

Comment: yes, `- (void)logInWithReadPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
              fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
                         handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler`

Comment: Let me check this and I will let you know! Thanks!!!

Comment: Also the issue seems to be only on the sdk >=4.27. Downgrading might also solve it for the moment.

Comment: Tried with the SDK 4.28, but no luck

Comment: I had hope it would be fixed in 4.28 :(

Comment: I think I solved it ! Check my answer ;)

Comment: anyone got the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue after we updated to the latest Facebook SDK (from a quite old version 4.11 to 4.27.1). Actually we had some calls initiated from `applicationDidBecomeActive` event which triggered the Facebook login (so opening a `SFAuthenticationSession` which opens the `SFAuthenticationViewController` the prompt that asks the user to continue authentication with Facebook or other 3rd party). Once the user tapped on "Continue" it triggered the `applicationDidBecomeActive` event again. This caused an endless loop of starting new `SFAuthenticaionSessions` which resulted in a crash. So we decided not to call Facebook login from this event at all. To summarize how to avoid this crash: you have to make sure that you call Facebook login (or `SFAuthenticationSession` `start()` method) only once at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

As @Zoltán Homoki and @Jelly said, we should call `logInWithReadPermissions` only once.

For this purpose a common implementation (that was ok before) is to set a flag in the `appDelegate` like :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if ([[url.scheme substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"fb"]) {
        _fromFbConnect = YES; // <- This flag
        returnValue = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
    }
    // Manage app deep links here
}
```

Then use it to prevent multiple call to the Facebook login :

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];

    if (_fromFbConnect == NO) { // <- Always `YES` on iOS11 with FB SDK 4.27
        // Refresh the facebook token
        if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] != nil) {
            [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logInWithReadPermissions: // ...
        }
        _fromFbConnect = NO;
    }
}
```

The issue is that on iOS11 with `FBSDKLoginKit` >= 4.27 `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is not called (nor `application:openURL:option`) so the flag is not set. That create multiple calls to the login (`applicationDidBecomeActive` being called when the user close the first popup)

The solution I found is to setup a flag before any call to `FBSDKLoginManager` and stop any other call until the process is done.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL fbRequesting;

// ...

if(_fbRequesting == YES) {
    NSLog(@"Facebook login already in progress");
    return;
}

if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] != nil) {
    return;
}

_fbRequesting = YES;
[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];

NSLog(@"Logging in to Facebook...");

@weakify(self);
[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logInWithReadPermissions:... fromViewController:... handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    @strongify(self);

    // Handle login

    _fbRequesting = NO;
    })
];
```

This seems to work with versions 4.22 to 4.28 of FBSDKLoginKit.

Comment: Good catch! I'm gonna try it!

Comment: I can see openURL is called when you login using Facebook.

Comment: Hum, the root of the problem for me was that two calls can be made to `logInWithReadPermissions` somehow. Also I changed the `FBSDKLoginBehavior` back to `native` (Given that `systemAccount` is not possible on iOS11)

Comment: `FBSDKLoginBehavior` should not make any difference since the FB SDK should automatically fall back to `native` when the OS does not provide a `systemAccount`.

Comment: @Manuel I agree, it should not make any difference ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Just faced this crash in FB SDK 4.31.1, and that's how I solved it.

In my case Crash happens, only when I trying to start login into FB, when FB Login already started(there is a Safari Web view on screen).

So I just check:

```
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
while (topController.presentedViewController) {
       topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

if ([topController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]])
{
     // If that's my view controller, we can start FB Login
}
```

Comment: The other way around one can check if `topViewController` is of class `SFSafariViewController` which is the parent of the private class `SFAuthenticationViewController`.

Comment: You should use this code in place, where you trying to login into FB using FB SDK. I.e. your login code should be after the topController type check.